# How to stereo image warpping with dispairy tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to stereo image warping in tensorflow.

if I have left image L(x,y) and disparity map d(x,y), 
I can get shifted left image L'(x-d(x,y), y)

i want this operation using tensor(left image and dispairty)

but tensorflow not support item assignement...

Is there any pixel mapping algorithm for tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

There has been two CVPR papers (I am aware of):

- Unsupervised Monocular Depth Estimation with Left-Right Consistency
- Unsupervised Learning of Depth and Ego-Motion from Video

https://github.com/mrharicot/monodepth
https://github.com/tinghuiz/SfMLearner

which are exactly doing this kind of computation.

They both have a "bi-linear sampler" function:
https://github.com/tinghuiz/SfMLearner/blob/master/utils.py#L197
https://github.com/mrharicot/monodepth/blob/master/bilinear_sampler.py

Note, the code is too long for posting it here but the idea is quite simple. Use meshgrid to create an identity mapping, add the network residual displacement, reshape to [n, 2] an bi-linear interpolate. This can be done directly in TensorFlow. The previous two links are pointing to some TensorFlow code doing exactly this.

For all people itching to downvote this answer because of just pointing to GitHub repositories, let me know if copy paste these implementations is necessary. But have a look at LOC before.